# Git - Push Failed. Unable to push to the remote repository because your local branch is behind the remote branch. My pull button is greyed out Vstudio

Tags: git

I am trying to push my local and make a Pull Request but I am getting the error:
'Git Push Failed
Unable to push to the remote repository because your local branch is behind the remote branch by pulling before pushing.'

[Git - push failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR8O0.png)

So obviously the first thing I try to do is Pull to update but the pull button is greyed out. I have no clue what's going on and need some serious help :(

[Pull button greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TloIt.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try to fetch incoming changes first. (dashed arrow on the left of the greyed Pull arrow). You should have some incoming changes. Then click on the link below arrows (4 Outgoings / n Incommings). Then try to pull or sync your local with remote origin (double cycling arrows).

Git will try to merge your local changes (Outgoing) with remote changes (Incoming).

If your changes don't conflict with remotes it should solve it automatically.
Otherwise you will have a kind of Compare with remote and local code where you can choose witch version of code to keep for each differences.

Once conflicts solved you should Pull/Push/Sync at your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

what you can try to do is Restart Visual Studio. In case the problem still persists you can try to pull it using `git pull` command ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)) or you can get more information using `git status` command.

Make sure you type these commands in the root directory of your .git repository (directory with .git subdirectory inside).